# Wso2 Esb 5.0 looping

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying with no success to loop through Syanpse $ctx: and $trp: objects.

I have tried XPATH as $ctx://*

How can we do this task?

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe your scenario, without proper scenario and sample request and expected response , we will not able to help you out

Comment: Hi, I would like to know all the available property names that pass in the $trp context and in the $ctx context. For example I can access a custom property when I define it myself but i wanna get a list of all available properties

Comment: I am not sure whether i understood your requirement , however have you gone through wso2 docs "https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Generic+Properties"

Comment: My question is simple ! Is there a way to loop through all available $ctx values by name , without having to refer to every specific property as $ctx:PROPERTY_NAME ! That's all :)

Comment: I do not think there is any mechanism wherein we can loop through all properties , there are many properties in wso2 so i do not think there is any possibility to iterate  on all the properties

Comment: It would be very very cool if we could know all of them so to use the full potential of the product !!!  No problem and thanks anyway @amg_amit